# Can I buy a necklace with my name written in Japanese for myself?

Tags: halal-haram

Salam

I was wondering what the view is on buying a necklace/chain for myself. It’s a chain with my name written in Japanese.

**I just want to know whether it is allowed in Islam.**

Comment: Is the necklace made of gold? If not what are other factor do you forsee that it may be Haram for you?

Answer (score 1):

From what I'd learned in Islamic schools for years, necklace, bracelet are haram for men to wear, regardless it is written in Japanese or not. It is haram to wear something that resembles the opposite sex. For example a man wear something to look like a woman and vice versa. Hand watch is an exception because you wear it for a purpose.

The same goes for gold. You can purchase gold for investment, but as a man, you cannot wear it. Any Japanese or Roman text don't make it haram.

Source here, a fatwa from Mufti Wilayah Persekutuan Malaysia (in Malay): https://muftiwp.gov.my/artikel/al-kafi-li-al-fatawi/4498-al-kafi-1722-hukum-lelaki-memakai-gelang

Below are parts of the article in the link above, translated with Google Translate:

A hadith from Abu Hurairah r.a:

أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ  لَعَنَ الرَّجُلَ يَلْبَسُ لُبْسَةَ الْمَرْأَةِ، وَالْمَرْأَةَ تَلْبَسُ لُبْسَةَ الرَّجُلِ

Translation of the hadith: Indeed, the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) cursed a man wearing a woman's clothes, and a woman wearing a man's clothes.

- Sahih al-Bukhari (5435) and Musnad Imam Ahmad (8309)

Sheikh Badr al-Din Al-'aini commented on this hadith with his words:

وتشبه الرِّجَال بِالنسَاء فِي اللبَاس والزينة الَّتِي تخْتَص بِالنسَاء مثل لبس المقانع والقلائد والمخانق والأسورة والخلاخل والقرط

Meaning: (This reproach) is in the act of men resembling women from the corner of clothing and also a special jewelry for women like wearing Serkup head, chains, bracelets, foot bracelets, and earrings. (Refer 'Umdah Al-Qari, Al-'aini 22/41)

Clearly from this hadith that it is illegal of this law for a person to wear a special clothing or jewelry for the opposite sex.

Expressed in al-Mausu'ah al-Fiqhiyyah that no khilaf among fuqaha 'will be ban for men resembling women from the point of body movement, tenderness of words, jewelry, clothing and other special for women from custom angle and habits . (Refer to al-Mausu'ah al-Fiqhiyyah al-Kuwaitiyyah 11/267)

The man's law wears a bracelet:

There is a history of 'Imran bin Husain R.a that the Prophet saw one day saw a man wearing a bracelet in his hand. Then the Prophet said:

مَا هَذِهِ الْحَلْقَةُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ هَذِهِ مِنَ الْوَاهِنَةِ ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ انْزِعْهَا فَإِنَّهَا لاَ تَزِيدُكَ إِلاَّ وَهْنًا

Which means: What's this bracelet? So the man replied: This is because of the disease. Then he said: Remove it because he does not add to you but weakness.
Sunan Ibn Majah (3531)

It is clear from the hadith above that the Prophet (s) ordered the use of the bracelet for the purpose and belief that it could cure be removed and kept away as it was unable to benefit nor avoid harm.

Imam al-Nawawi stated that Jumhur scholars banned men wearing bracelets. There is also a partial view of the scholars such as Imam al-Ghazali who mentioned the silver bracelet, as the NAS only mentioned the ban on food containers from Perak and the ban on women's resemblance for men. But more authentic opinions are the views of Jumhur, that wearing a bracelet is illegal for men.

Sheikh Zakariyya Al-Ansari mentions that it is required for a man to wear a silver ring because according to the Messenger of Allah, even his law is circumcision, but men can not wear the bracelet (al-Siwar) and not halal for him, although the bracelet is made of Silver. This is because wearing the bracelet has an element of femininity, and it is not worthy and according to the nature of a man. (Refer to Fatawa Hujjah Al-Islam Abu Hamid al-Ghazali, HLM. 30; Al-Majmu 'Syarh Al-Muhazzab 4/444 and Asna al-Matolib 1/379).

Ibn Hajar al-Haitami states that among the forms of women resembling is wearing jewelry devoted to women and those who dilazimi by them, such as bracelets and pedestal bracelets; As for the ring it is required for men to wear them. (Refer to Al-Fatawa al-Fiqhiyyah al-Kubra, 1/261)

This was also agreed by Fuqaha 'Hanafi sect, where Imam Kamaluddin ibn al-Hammam clearly mentioned that it was not required for men to wear silver jewelry except with al-mantiqah rings (belts) and sword decorations. The same view is also mentioned by Imam Ibn Qudamah al-Hanbali (refer to Syarh Fath al-Qadir 22/180 and al-'Umdah fi al-fiqh 1/37)

Source [here, a fatwa](https://muftiwp.gov.my/artikel/al-kafi-li-al-fatawi/4498-al-kafi-1722-hukum-lelaki-memakai-gelang) from Mufti Wilayah Persekutuan Malaysia (in Malay). Translation [here in Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://muftiwp.gov.my/artikel/al-kafi-li-al-fatawi/4498-al-kafi-1722-hukum-lelaki-memakai-gelang). You can read it for more details.

Comment: Is there a source brother?

Comment: I edited my post above with the source. Thanks.

Comment: Jazakallah Khair brother