# Is it haram to wear a necklace?

Tags: halal-haram, makruh

Salam, recently I got a gift of a Chain necklace, not gold with a pendant of Palestinian map on it. I am Palestinian and I’m proud to be and I want to be able to wear it. I also don’t look very arab so it sort of proves my identity to other Arabs and muslims. Because I like talking and associating with arabs and muslims more. Even as small as a smile of recognition. And please if you will answer I want actual hadith or ayah in the Quran saying so. Because I get it’s very easy to want to say it’s ok or not depending on culture or how it’s portrayed within our culture.

Comment: What is your gender? If you are a female, it should be fine. If you are a male, then it is haram. I answered a similar quesiton before here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/69995/45948

Comment: Thank you, but I don’t believe either are applicable. It isn’t about imitation of females nor do I have any intention of being feminine. It’s the pendent that actually means anything. And second I don’t believe it will cure me or do anything to my health. So it’s not for that purpose either. Nor is it a bracelet, imitation of kafir is haram, for example birthdays. But if you are celebrating your birthday because a year has passed and you want to connect with family that’s not haram. Because the imitation part doesn’t apply. You’re not throwing a party.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Salam!

if you read Quran 4:135 “O you who have believed, be persistently standing firm in justice, witnesses for Allah, even if it be against yourselves or parents and relatives. Whether one is rich or poor, Allah is more worthy of both. So follow not [personal] inclination, lest you not be just." it can be understood as to value justice over relatives, even parents and oneself - and thus to value it higher than tribes, nations and races. Wearing a necklace to identify with Palestine and the Arabs rather than identifiying with all of mankind, may then be a bit un-muslim.

More on it here: https://sunnahonline.com/library/beliefs-and-methodology/744-the-evils-of-nationalism

We're all children of Adam, a necklace of the world or spelling Allah would be different

Comment: Yes but with Palestine it’s not like that. I don’t want my identity in that necklace as if I’m better or I’m not apart of mankind. It’s simply that we are at a disadvantage and nobody recognizes our struggle or what we go through or what’s happening to us. Wearing that necklace is a sense of pride and acknowledgment. Second that’s not Dalil that wearing a necklace is haram. That has very little to do with any of it. I was asking about jewelry being worn by men that isnt gold, specifically a necklace and I don’t have the intention of imitating females. So I just stated my intentions to clarify.